# Doesn't recognize my device and doesn't load avd

Tags: android-studio

I'm pretty new to android studio and app developing. I ran into some problems after installing android studio and I don't have any solution yet after a day's google search.

I'm using windows 7 system, 32 bit.

1, my Preview panel doesn't show a phone layout (nexus 4, 5 etc.)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mCFX.jpg)

2, after I click the green RUN button, it will show: waiting for device to come online and get stuck there.

Could anyone help me solve this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your device hasn't installed correctly. Go to device manager, uninstall your device and then re-install it.  Make sure your device allows debugging.